# Radio button and checkboxes have not the right style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap for a project but I noticed that the radio buttons are not styled in the right way.They seem okay in safari but not in chrome

[image]

In safari:

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">  Particulieren (residentieel)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Bedrijven (commercieel)</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know bootstrap 3 doesn't style checkboxes. The difference you are seeing comes from the way the different browsers choose to display their form controls.

To test this theory have a look at the bootstrap form components doc's in the different browsers.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

There are ways to style the checkboxes so they look the same across browsers. Here are some resources:

Plugin: https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox with [(demo)](http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/)

Tutorial: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953